# Производительность браузера - DIV или TABLE?

Tags: вёрстка, html, производительность

Вопрос заключается в следующем:
Предположим, в приложении с помощью AJAX подгружаются данные. Например, заказы из интернет-магазина.
Каждый заказ содержит множество данных. В итоге 1 заказ может содержать несколько вложенных таблиц, различных блоков с данными...

У меня на данный момент при наличии большого кол-ва таких заказов на экране, появляются тормоза, при анализе Timeline -   Hit Test !
Если сокращаю кол-во вложенных блоков для теста - тормоза значительно снижаются.

Есть ли разница в производительности при верстке строго ввиде table, строго ввиде блоков div или разницы нет ?

Поделитесь опытом!

Comment: С секундомером не стоял, но по-моему разницы никакой.

Comment: для подобного придумали пагинацию.